# How to get best_estimator parameters from GridSearch using cross_val_score?

Tags: scikit-learn

I want to know the result of the GridSearch when I'm using nested cross validation with cross_val_score for convenience.

When using cross_val_score, you get an array of scores. It would be useful to receive the fitted estimator back or a summary of the chosen parameters for that estimator.

I know you can do this yourself but just implementing cross-validation manually but it is much more convenient if it can be done in conjunction with cross_val_score.

Any way to do it or is this a feature to suggest?

Answer (score 6):

The `GridSearchCV` class in scikit-learn already does cross validation internally. You can pass any [CV iterator](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html#cross-validation-iterators) as the `cv` argument of the constructor of `GridSearchCV`.

Comment: Ah thanks! It was just confusing because in the documentation the example way of doing nested cross-validation is to pass a GridSearchCV Object to cross_val_score

Comment: Yes this is a good way to evaluate the variance of the generalisation error of the model selection it-self. The grid search is a meta learning algorithm that can cause over-fitting in some situations.

Comment: This does not answer the question for nested cross validation, where one still wants to call `cross_val_score` with a `GridSearchCV` estimator. See [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_nested_cross_validation_iris.html) for an example.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question is that it is a feature to suggest. Unfortunately, you can't get the best parameters of the models fitted with nested cross-validation using `cross_val_score` (as of now, scikit 0.14).

See this example:

```
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.cross_validation import cross_val_score

digits = datasets.load_digits()
X = digits.data
y = digits.target

hyperparams = [{'fit_intercept':[True, False]}]
algo = LinearRegression()

grid = GridSearchCV(algo, hyperparams, cv=5, scoring='mean_squared_error')

# Nested cross validation
cross_val_score(grid, X, y)
grid.best_score_

[Out]:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-4c4ac83c58fb> in <module>()
     15 # Nested cross validation
     16 cross_val_score(grid, X, y)
---> 17 grid.best_score_

AttributeError: 'GridSearchCV' object has no attribute 'best_score_'
```

(Note also that the scores you get from `cross_val_score` are not the ones defined in `scoring`, here the mean squared error. What you see is the score function of the best estimator. The bug of v0.14 is described [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/3185).)

Comment: do you know if it is now possible to obtain the information on the grid search objects? btw, for each fold in the cross_val_score call a different grid object is constructed. So, shouldn't there rather be a "cross_val" object that contains the information on each best "grid" object for the corresponding folds?

Comment: @Quickbeam2k1 Haven't checked yet. If you do let us know here. GitHub is probably a better place to suggest changes for scikit. Not sure if the relevant people are reading this here.

Comment: thanks for the response. I searched a bit and found: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/6827 So the general suggestion is to build an own implementation of the cross_val_score function. How to do that, might be shown in the documentation in the future

Answer (score 2):

In `sklearn v0.20.0` (which will be released in late 2018), the trained estimators are exposed by the function `cross_validate` if requested.

See here the corresponding [pull-request](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/11583) for the new feature. Something like this will work:

```py
from sklearn.metrics.scorer import check_scoring
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate
scorer = check_scoring(estimator=gridSearch, scoring=scoring)
cvRet = cross_validate(estimator=gridSearch, X=X, y=y,
                       scoring={'score': scorer}, cv=cvOuter,
                       return_train_score=False,
                       return_estimator=True,
                       n_jobs=nJobs)

scores = cvRet['test_score']  # Equivalent to output of cross_val_score()
estimators = cvRet['estimator']
```

If `return_estimator=True`, the estimators can be retrieved from the returned dictionary as `cvRet['estimator']`. The list stored in `cvRet['test_score']` is equivalent to the output of `cross_val_score`. See [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/7ed61a24feb4ffde0bee9342acf4a58e3f946a61/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py#L276) how `cross_val_score()` is implemented by means of `cross_validate()`.